# How can I avoid recursion between move generation and check validation in python chess implementation?

Tags: python, recursion, chess

I'm currently working on a simple python 3 implementation of a chess game where legal moves can be calculated and things like check, checkmate, and stalemate can be determined. I've encountered a logic error which results in recursion and I'm not sure how I change my current approach to avoid this.

I've got some pseudo-code here (my actual code several hundred lines long and it would be impractical to paste it all for a logic problem).

Where am I going wrong with my thought process behind this code?

```
class ChessBoard:
   def get_position():
      # returns fen of position

   def set_position(position_code):
      # sets the board's position and values using the fen code given

   # assume its white's turn right now
   def calculate_moves():
      # uses vectors to calculate moves for all pieces
      for each_move in candidate_moves:
         if passes_all_general_conditions:
             # now I need to check if the potential 
             # legal move will leave the user in check
             # obviously if the white king can be taken in the next turn
             # by the other color then the move cannot be considered legal
             temp_board = ChessBoard()
             temp_board.set_position(self.get_position())
             temp_board.make_move(the_selected_move_that_needs_checking) 
             if not temp_board.incheck():
                # add move to list of legal moves
  def incheck():
     # player is in check if a piece can take it on the next turn
     # don't I need to know what moves can be made before I can know if its check??
     # let k equal the current turn (or half-turn as chess players call it)
     # in order to calculate the moves for position at turn k
     # the moves for position k + 1 must be known
     # obviously this just enters infinite recursion
```

Comment: "in order to calculate the moves for position at turn k the moves for position k + 1 must be known".  Why?  Surely the possible moves in position k depend only on position k, not on some future position.  You make a list of all the moves by all the pieces in position k, and if one of those moves results in a piece moving to the square now occupied by the enemy king, that's check.  No recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `incheck()` is not implemented. The default return value of a python method is the None type.

```
>>> not None == True
True
```

So the deepest-nested conditional in your loop always evaluates to True.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that you didn't copy paste you whole code, but it would have been useful to at least show SOME part of it, in order to fix your issue.

Since I cannot debug your code without seeing it, I will just make a guess:
I think you use calculate_moves() in incheck(), and incheck to verify wether calculated_moves are legal ones.

If you do that, you have got two options:
-Split calculate_moves into two functions: one generates pseudo legals, and the other then controls these pseudolegals on legality. You will just ave to replace calculate_moves() in incheck() by calculate_pseudolegals(). This approach is a little bit inefficient though.

-The more efficient solution is to fully delete your incheck() routine and write a new, efficient one. There you would replace the king you wish to test on check by every figure of its own color onece, and then test if it could hit a figure of the same type of the opponent. If it can, your king is in check. Be aware that you will still need a calculate_pseudolegals() function for this to work.